# Dropdown not dropping down

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter, drop-down-menu

I'm trying to use a bootstrap dropdown on my website, but when I click the dropdown it's not working.

Heres my code

```
    <li class="dropdown">
                        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-file"></i> READ <b class="caret"></b></a></li>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                            <li><a href="#">READ CONFESSIONS</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">READ STORIES</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
```

Could you tell me what I need to add or take away for the javascript or html to make this code funcional?

Answer (score 0):

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
    <li class="dropdown">
      <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown <b class="caret"></b></a>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
        <li class="divider"></li>
        <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
        <li class="divider"></li>
        <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
```

You need to check where is your bootstrap.js placed. Place jquey.js before bootstrap.js.